# CSS - Vertically align text with line on text

Tags: html, css

In have a js-fiddel here - https://jsfiddle.net/zhfs7hxq/

Very simple I have text within a div with text within a span within that div.

I need to vertically center the the span of text against the larger text within the div.

`vertical-align: middle;` moves it slightly but doesn't center it.

```
    *{
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    .name{
        background: yellow;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .name-inner{
        display: inline;
        font-size: 20px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code is vertical aligned by the line-height, that's how it works. If you need to center perfectly you can position absolute the element. I modify your fiddle to achieve it:

https://jsfiddle.net/zhfs7hxq/1/

In the first yellow block targets your code. 
My modifications is in the second yellow block:

```
    .name{
        margin: 10px;
        position:relative;
        background: yellow;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .name.other .name-inner{
        position: absolute;
        display:inline-block;
        font-size: 20px;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
```

Good luck

Comment: .name.other .name-inner{
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    top: 50%;
   
} doesn't need transform and position can be relative.

Comment: @Hughzi for perfect vertical alignment this code works. With position relative and without transform you'll get no vertical aligned to middle. Don't lie :)

Comment: try it in your fiddle:)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [flex box](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), try this **JSFIDDLE**: [**https://jsfiddle.net/zhfs7hxq/2/**](https://jsfiddle.net/zhfs7hxq/2/)

Note that `vertical-align` works only on table-cell and inline-level elements.

**Flex box solution**

Add this to `.name` to set its display to flex:

```
.name {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
}
```

And to `.name-inner` add the following to align vertically centered:

```
.name-inner {
  -webkit-align-self: center;
     -moz-align-self: center;
      -ms-align-self: center;
          align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: *Note that vertical-align works for display:table-cell, not for inline and block like you had.* This is not true. For `inline` and `inline-block` values it works perfectly. Your solution is good but at the moment is less compatible than other solutions. Flexbox rules, but browsers don't rules yet

Comment: I vote up your solution because is a good solution if the OP doesn't matter old browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `line-height` for your code. Try making the `line-height`s identical:

```
line-height: 45px;
```

**Snippet**

```css
*{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.name{
  background: yellow;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.name-inner{
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">Heading one <span class="name-inner">Heading insert</span></div>
```